# List items using html only without any css styling

Tags: html, list, line-breaks

My question is simple. Whats the best way to list items that aren't meant to have bullets or indentation. Is it possible without css? for example:

```
item 1 
item 2
item 3
```

In the mean time Ive used line breaks:

```
item 1 
<br>
item 2
<br>
item 3
```

Is that the only way without css?

Comment: You should research the <p> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to wrap each item in a `div` element: `<div>item 1</div>`. This is better than `br`, because each item becomes an element, so it can be handled as a unit in client-side scripting and in CSS. But ignoring such aspects, `br` is OK in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<p>` for paragraphs, is that's what you're asking for. Like this:

```
<p>A paragraph</p>
```

For lists, either `<ul>` for unordered list or `<ol>` for an ordered list (list with numbers). Then, use `<li>` for each element.

As an example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why would items of a list be paragraphs, or formatted as paragraphs? Without CSS (as postulated in the question), `p` elements will appear with empty lines between them (technically, with vertical margins that correspond to an empty line).

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways to do this, You could have each item in it's own `div`, each item within a separate `tr` in a `table`, you could use `br` as you are currently doing, you could put each item in a separate `p` element, etc.

The main question is why are you not wanting to use CSS?  If you wanted to use a `ul`/`li` you can easy set the styles to display as you want.  I guess the reason I mention this, is if you are trying to get into HTML without trying to learn CSS, you are going down the wrong path.  The two are inseparable technologies at this point.

Comment: No it's not that I don't want to learn CSS, I've already dabbed into it quite a bit and I realize you can make lists and set the style to:                                                                     ul{                                                                    style:none;                                                               } I was just wondering if there was any code that simply listed your items without having to use any css. A self sufficient code if you will. I guess based on your response there isn't. I'm just focusing on making my code cleaner.